# Backfill and Increment by one?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a column of a DataFrame that consists of 0's and NaN's:

```
Timestamp   A     B     C
    1       3     3    NaN
    2       5     2    NaN
    3       9     1    NaN 
    4       2     6    NaN 
    5       3     3     0
    6       5     2    NaN
    7       3     1    NaN
    8       2     8    NaN
    9       1     6     0
```

And I want to backfill it and increment the last value:

```
Timestamp   A     B     C
    1       3     3     4 
    2       5     2     3 
    3       9     1     2  
    4       2     6     1  
    5       3     3     0
    6       5     2     3 
    7       3     1     2 
    8       2     8     1 
    9       1     6     0
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use `iloc[::-1]` to reverse the data, and `groupby().cumcount()` to create the row counter:

```
s = df['C'].iloc[::-1].notnull()
df['C'] = df['C'].bfill() + s.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Output

```
   Timestamp  A  B    C
0          1  3  3  4.0
1          2  5  2  3.0
2          3  9  1  2.0
3          4  2  6  1.0
4          5  3  3  0.0
5          6  5  2  3.0
6          7  3  1  2.0
7          8  2  8  1.0
8          9  1  6  0.0
```

Comment: Maybe just `df['C'][::-1].notnull()` so you don't have to reverse whole df?

Comment: @HenryYik yep, that's an excellent suggestion. Updated, Thanks!